# how can I use sass with the new create react app?

Tags: reactjs, sass, create-react-app

Apparently Sass has been included with the new create react app(2.0.0 onwards). But as a web noobie I don't quite get why, when I try to apply styles, they don't show up. I'm using react-scripts-ts like create-react-app my-app --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:
Create your app with

```
create-react-app your-app-name
```

No scripts version needed. Then install node-sass

```
yarn add node-sass
```

and then import the sass file directly in your component with

```
import './my-component-styles.scss'
```

I think webpack is who is compiling now the sass files, so you can use them the same way as css files

Comment: You don't need the --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts, because this is not create react app, but another scripts. Try just create-react-app your-app-name

Comment: tried it but it didn't work.
Steps:
create-react-app test --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts
npm install --save-dev node-sass
renamed App.css -> App.scss
changed import './App.css' -> import './App.scss'
didn't work
tried:
create-react-app test
npm instal node-sass --save-dev
change App.css -> App.scss
import ./App.css -> import App.scss
and this time it worked, so it appears to be the scripts-version, right?

Comment: The new version of cra allows to use sass directly, but with -scripts-version=react-scripts-ts you are using another project, that has another webpack config. If it worked, could you accept the answer? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

first you should install `node-sass-chokidar`

```
npm install node-sass-chokidar --save-dev
```

and also `npm-run-all` so:

```
npm install npm-run-all -g
```

then change these in package.json:

```
 "start": "react-scripts start",
 "build": "react-scripts build",
```

to :

```
 "start-js": "react-scripts start",
 "start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
 "build": "npm run build-css && react-scripts build",
 "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/",
 "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive",
```

now if you create a `mycomponent.sass` inside of your component just import it like :

```
import './mycomponent.css'
```

Comment: Isn't this the old way? Sass is supported in `create-react-app` now (https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/01/create-react-app-v2.html), which his question mentions.